# Embedded href link in JQuery master/slave script

Tags: jquery

I have set up a JQuery master/slave script that shows a slave element when the master is clicked on, and closes it when either the master or slave is clicked on again. It all works fine except that I want to have a link (either href or pop-up gallery) in either the master or slave elements that does **not** activate the JQuery script. Possibly one solution would be to inhibit JQuery execution in the slave (ie clicking on the slave would not close it) and presumably then links would work normally leaving the slave displayed. However I don't know how to do this. Also any other suggestions appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".showschedule").click(function() {
    $(this).find(".schedule").slideToggle("slow");
  })
});
```

```css
.showschedule {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.showschedule h3:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.schedule {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  display: none;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showschedule">
  <h3>Master Item 1</h3>

  <div class="schedule">
    Slave Results for Master 1
  </div>
</div>

<div class="showschedule">
  <h3>Master Item 2</h3>

  <div class="schedule">
    Slave Results for Master 2
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/minz56/qrufa6Lg/11/

Sorry, not an expert on JQuery scripts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a condition which will check if the clicked element inside the slave is a link or is child of a link. If so, the slave will not be hidden.

```
if (!$(e.target).closest('a').length) {
  $(this).find(".schedule").slideToggle("slow");
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".showschedule").click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('a').length) {
      $(this).find(".schedule").slideToggle("slow");
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.showschedule {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.showschedule h3:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.schedule {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  display: none;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showschedule">
  <h3>Master Item 1</h3>

  <div class="schedule">
    Slave Results for Master 1
  </div>
</div>

<div class="showschedule">
  <h3>Master Item 2</h3>

  <div class="schedule">
    <a href="#">Slave Results for Master 2</a>
    <br>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://wagnermurmurs.com/img/iconreviews.png">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! Works when a TEXT link is use, but not when an IMG is used. I plan to use  icons for my links. See the updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/minz56/qrufa6Lg/16/ where I have put both a TEXT and IMG link in the slave elements.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Now, the code is working for both cases.

Comment: Works perfectly now! Thanks so much for your help with this.

Comment: @minz56 You can also mark this answer as accepted, so others will know it's the solution for the problem.